# Java "workflow" design

Tags: java, workflow

I'd like to ask about designing "workflow merging". I've got several workflows that aren't very similar to each other. However, sometimes I want to combine them modifying them very slightly. 
Let me give you an example :

> #### Workflow 1 - Trip
>
> A1 (pack the bag) -> A2 (leave the house) -> A3
>   (catch the bus) -> A4 ...
>
> #### Workflow 2 - Daily plant watering
>
> B1 (turn the water on) -> B2 (leave the house) -> B3 (water the plants) -> B4 (enter the house) -> B5 (turn the water off)

On Sunday, I want to go for a trip and I need to water the plants too. So I want to create something like **A1 -> B1 to B5 -> A2...** . I also want to have possibility to tell my friend to finish the watering, which would be something like **A1 -> B1 to B2 -> C1 (pass the task to a friend) -> A3** ...
As you can see, the flow is straightforward - there are no forks and joins in it and I don't need such functionality. All I need is to create a linear list of commands with possibility to merge them together easily. All fragments of code are Java methods at the moment (and I'd like to make them something like atomic flows).

The main goal of my approach should be avoiding typing the same code over and over again. The flow may have hundreds of steps. I'd like to make a statement like **Execute flow A, but instead of running A2 and A3, execute B2 to B6 and continue with A**.

I've got two major questions :

- Is there any framework that already supports this? If there is, isn't it too complex for my purpose?
- If not, what would be the best way to implement such thing?

Note : Can you please specify what is so unclear about my question?

Comment: I would use `List` of your tasks from Java collections to build more lists of tasks.

Comment: Check out these Java workflow engines - http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/workflow_in_java

Comment: maybe it's helpful for you: http://java-source.net/open-source/workflow-engines

Comment: Another good question that was closed! We are going to run out of good questions if this continues ;)

Comment: @CKing Vote to reopen then.

Comment: @immibis I did and looks like it worked :)

Comment: I have this answer on a similar question to be very useful:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17844527/363502

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally feel that the requirement can be implemented without the use of any specific framework. You could design the application as follows :

1. TaskPerformer : An interface with a method named  performTask. Represents a Task to be performed.
2. BagPackTask : A concrete class that implements TaskPerformer. Also defines the performTask method that contains code for packing a bag.
3. WaterPlantsTask : Another concrete class that implements TaskPerformer. Also defines the performTask method that contains code for watering plants. 
   Similarly, you have one class per task that implements Taskperformer and defines the behavior for the task using the performTask method.
4. Workflow : A class that will be used for executing two or more tasks and will allow you to mix and match existing tasks. The class will contain a List of TaskPerformer and the constructor for this class will have a List parameter to ask for Tasks to execute. The class will contain an executeWorkflow method that will iterate over the List and call the performTask method of each element in the list. In other words, this class can be used to execute all the tasks passed to its constructor during instantiation by using its executeWorkflow method. It is important to note that the order in which you insert elements in the list is the order in which the tasks will be executed.

Using this approach, you eliminate the need to have any if-else conditions to determine what task to perform. You can reuse your TaskPerformer implementations in how many ever Workflow instances as you wish. You get a super clean design. Let me know if you need any clarifications since I feel that this design should solve your problem. It would be a good idea to clarify all your doubts before accepting any answers :)

Answer (score 1):

... or implement the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). It should be quite easy without any frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/) is very simple to get up and running, and lets you submit jobs that run tasks in whatever order you choose. I'd recommend that as a starting point, to see if it meets your needs. For your case, I would recommend running it with an in-memory database, like HSQLDB, to avoid setup overhead. You can always log the results of your job in a log file.

Probably the most mature, enterprisey workflow engine is [JBPM](http://www.jboss.org/jbpm), but that seems a bit heavyweight for what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As far as I know from brief overview of Spring Batch, it allows me to run my As, Bs and Cs naming all of them. I'd prefer to have something like "take A workflow, replace A50 to A55 by B6 to B90 and B70 to B75 by C5 to C20 and run it". I want to avoid typing all of these again and again.

Comment: well, it really depends on how you structure your job definitions. you can have a basic job file, and override whatever you like. so, you could pretty easily write something that says "take the 'watering the plants' job flow, but replace the 'walk over to the flower bed' step with 'walk over to the flower pots'. you could use a templating system like velocity for this if you want to be fancy, what kind of interface do you want to have?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [OSWorkflow](http://java.net/projects/osworkflow), it's really nice, lightweight and provides you will all FSM machinery out of the box.